# How to use overflow-x hidden on container and prevent fixed child div overlapping scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, css-position

I have a single page site that is navigated via JS and works nearly as expected. Some of the pages are full screen (100% width and height of viewport with all content responsively fitting within this space). Some pages are text based pages that need to allow scrolling.

I need to use overflow-x:hidden on my main #wrapper as I slide various elements in from off screen and without the overflow-x:hidden it doesn't work on the Samsung Stock Browser (it works on all others just by using overflow-x:hidden on the body element but this doesn't work on Samsung Stock of course!)

You can a see a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/4nLoazzs/1/, if you remove the overflow-x:hidden from the #wrapper element then it all works as expected. However when you include the overflow-x:hidden on the #wrapper element (as it is now) then it causes the fixed #footer div to overlap the scrollbar. As you can see i've tried defining the #wrapper as 100% width with the #footer width set to inherit but this doesn't help either.

Can anyone explain how I can keep the same structure with overflow-x:hidden on the wrapper container but ensure the footer does not overlap the scrollbar as it's driving me nuts! Ideally I want to avoid using custom scrolls as everything else is perfect across all devices, this is the only remaining issue!

Thanks so much!

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">HEADER</div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>

body,html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

p {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}

#wrapper {
    height:100%;
     overflow-x:hidden;
   width:100%;
}
#header {
    height:10%;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}

#content {
    height:80%;
    background-color: #cc00ff;
    padding-bottom:15%;
}

#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:10%;
    background-color: #dd00ff;
    width:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about putting all your content in a container (Besides header per comments):

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wypn5e7n5bgeoic/landscape.png?dl=0" alt="Image Not Available"></img>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS (Change footer width:100%):

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#header {
    height:10%;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
}
#content {
    height:80%;
    background-color: #cc00ff;
    padding-bottom:15%;
}
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:10%;
    background-color: #dd00ff;
    width:100%;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nLoazzs/6/  *** ADDED WORKING IMAGE ***

Oops wrong link *** FIXED ***

Comment: Thanks @Simply Craig! The only problem is the header no longer respects the 10% height which screws up the layout, it just sizes based on its content and not based on the percentage height, eg http://jsfiddle.net/deshg/4nLoazzs/3/? This was what i couldn't get around as if you don't define the heights of all parents then you don't seem to be able to use percentage heights for the children, however if you use percentage heights for all then you don't seem to be able to overcome the scroll issue :( Is there any way you can see to get the footer height working alongside your fix? Thanks so much!

Comment: @deshg sure simply pull the header outside of the container and you can use your `height:10%`  I'll update my JSFiddle.

Comment: Oh, I see your image issue.  Let me check that

Comment: @deshg Doesn't seem like you image is valid, but I did add default text in it's place.  Updated JSFiddle.

Comment: That completely works for my jsfiddle but unfortunately in my actual case it doesn't as most elements are sized based on % height so this has to be allowed throughout. Instead I have used media queries to separate mobile and desktop overflow rules to deal with them in different ways as it's the only way it would play nice but thanks so much for your help in getting me there, if it wasn't such an insanely structured JS site then any of your suggestions would have worked :) Cheers